# Laravel 5. FirstorNew with several conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to add a product to the database if there isn't a product with the same `product_name`, `brand`, `weight` and `volume`.

Here is my code:

```
$product = Product::firstorNew(['product_name'=>$request->product)], ['brand'=>$reques->brand), ['weight'=>$request->weight], ['volume'=>$request->volume]);

$product->product_name = $request->product;
$product->brand = $request->brand;
$product->weight = $request->weight;
$product->volume = $request->volume;
$product->save();
```

This code doesn't check all the attributes but only the first one and if it matches the row is updated instead of adding a new one. For example, in the DB there is a product `id=1`, `product_name='Milk'`, `brand='Parmalat'`, `weight='null'`, `volume=1` and if I add `product_name='Milk'`, `brand='Unimilk'`, `weight='null'`, `volume=0.5` row with id=1 will be updated, but in this case I want to add a new row to the DB.

Comment: I think the code has a little typo. Please check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your brackets are placed wrongly. Try this:

```
$product = Product::firstOrNew([
  'product_name' => $request->product,
  'brand' => $request->brand,
  'weight' => $reqeust->weight,
  'volume' => $request->volume,
]);
```